# Getting error message in QGIS field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have used an equation within the field calculator, that has previously worked in an older version of QGIS, I am currently using QGIS 3.6.2 the equation being:

```
(atan((xat(-1)-xat(0))/(yat(-1)-yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *(((yat(-1)-yat(0)) < 0) + (((xat(-1)-xat(0)) < 0 AND (yat(-1) - yat(0)) >0)*2)))
```

This is the answer found on a previous question within this forum that helped me to achieve the angle of each line within a layer. However I keep getting the error evaluation message using the newer version of QGIS saying...

> An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: Cannot convert 'inf' to double.

What does this mean?

Comment: Try changing your syntax to $y_at(i)  and $x_at(i)

Comment: Once you get the function to work, please add an update to the question where you found the original expression. Don't delete the original, just add the updated version, with a note that it works in QGIS 3, whereas the other one uses older syntax (probably from QGIS 2). This will really help other users of this site.

Comment: @HDunn is right, have a look at Geometry Functions chapter in docs: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#list-of-functions

Comment: Im really sorry how would I change the syntax what would the change be I changed it as below: (atan(($xat(-1)-$xat(0))/($yat(-1)-$yat(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *((($yat(-1)-$yat(0)) < 0) + ((($xat(-1)-$xat(0)) < 0 AND ($yat(-1) - $yat(0)) >0)*2)))- However there was a syntax error so it wouldn't accept it

Comment: @AlisonJones don't forget the underscore, $y_at, $x_at

Comment: @HDunn thank you I changed the expression to; (atan(($x_at(-1)-$x_at(0))/($y_at(-1)-$y_at(0)))) * 180/3.14159 + (180 *((($y_at(-1)-$y_at(0)) < 0) + ((($x_at(-1)-$x_at(0)) < 0 AND ($y_at(-1) - $y_at(0)) >0)*2)- But know the error message as earlier stated keeps coming up and I don't know why

Comment: @AlisonJones perhaps you should elaborate your question to include what you are trying to achieve and what layer are you trying to work on. If you expression has operators like > and <, is this a snippet from a larger conditional statement? You need to help us help you

Comment: What I want to achieve is bearing or angle. I have a large dataset of trails and I would like to know the bearing of each one. I used the previous equation above to achieve the angle of each trail and worked in an older version of QGIS. I have previously tried to use the Azimuth and distance plugin on my dataset, but that didn't seem to work?

Comment: worked fine for me `atan(($x_at(-1) - $x_at(0)) / ($y_at(-1) - $y_at(0))) * 180 /  pi() + (180 *((($y_at(-1) - $y_at(0)) < 0) + ((($x_at(-1) - $x_at(0)) < 0 AND ($y_at(-1) - $y_at(0)) >0) * 2)))`. Tested on QGIS 3.0.3